# Formula IF time between ranges

Tags: excel, sharepoint, formula

Currently using a calculated SharePoint column (uses same excel formulas)

I have a column "SignIn" that shows the date/time of a staff sign-in. I have another column "Late Flag" that will show if they are late or not. There are sometimes multiple sign-ins/outs throughout the day, So I need the formula to only flag them as late between a certain time frame (09:35:00 AM to 10:15:00 AM). I have tried a few different formulas - but they keep producing unexpected results (like they all show as late, when they're not).

For example:

```
=IF(AND([SignIn]>"9:35:00 AM",[SignIn]<"10:15:00 AM"]),"Late","")
```

[This shows my column setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ex4b.png)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ex4b.png]

I have a date/time column for SignIn, and a single line of text column for Late Flag

Comment: An example of your data would be useful, along with actual and expected results. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: What formula do you have in your previous column, calculating the late time? If that works as is needed, then it's easier just to use that as  your base. `=IF(D1>0,"Late","Not Late")`

Comment: "=TEXT(SignIn-"9:30:00 AM","h:mm")" is the column I use to calculate late time - but I have different issue with this, in that if a person signs in earlier than 9:30 then it gives over 23 hours of lateness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the formula below to achieve it.

```
=IF(AND(TIME(HOUR([SignIn]),MINUTE([SignIn]),SECOND([SignIn])) > TIME(9,35,0),TIME(HOUR([SignIn]),MINUTE([SignIn]),SECOND([SignIn]))<TIME(10,15,0)), "Late", "")
```

More information: [**TIME function**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/time-function-e3ae5a7b-bd57-44b4-8467-ced98241e087)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your data is converted to a timevalue and shows as "9:36:00 AM", but when selected the true cell value will be "09:36:00" which is because excel has recognised it as a time and converted it to one. However in your formula "9:35:00 AM" will be a string (text value) which will never match with a time value. To get around this you can use `TIMEVALUE(` in your formula to convert it like a time like so:

```
=IF(AND(A1>TIMEVALUE("9:35:00"),A1<TIMEVALUE("10:15:00 AM")),"Late","Not")
```

Also, it might be possible the time in your cell is actually text, which cannot be compared to any time value to begin with. This complicates things, but not much, just wrap a `TIMEVALUE(` around that as well:

```
=IF(AND(TIMEVALUE(A1)>TIMEVALUE("9:35:00"),TIMEVALUE(A1)<TIMEVALUE("10:15:00 AM")),"Late","Not")
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I tried both of these (removing the AM too) but neither seem to work, there doesn't seem to be an issue with the syntax, I just don't get the right result. (I've added an image of my columns if that helps!)

Comment: To narrow down your issue, can you check if `=TIMEVALUE("your cell here")` returns anything? It should either return a formatted time, or something like `0.423611111` (the excel notation of time).

Comment: I get a #VALUE! result

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but did you swap the "your cell here" for the cell you're trying to check?

Comment: Well on sharepoint I have to use a column rather than a cell, so I tried a few  variations of =TIMEVALUE([SignIn])

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, after some reading, it seems like the `timevalue` function doesn't necessarily work as expected on sharepoint. An alternative wasn't easy, but with some fiddling this seems to work: `=IF(AND(TEXT(A:A,"hh:mm")>"09:30",TEXT(A:A,"hh:mm")<"10:15"),"Late","Not")` of course `A:A` would be [SignIn] in your case.